# If $\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ is a complete orthonormal set for the inner product induced by $G$, then $\sum_{j=1}^n u_ju_j^T=G^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> For $G$, an $n\times n$ and symmetric positive definite matrix, the $G$-inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is given by
>   $$(x,y)_G=x^{T}Gy.$$
>   A complete $G$-orthonormal set $\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_{n}\}$ satisfies $(u_i,u_j)_G=\delta_{ij}$. Prove that $\sum_{j=1}^{n}u_{j}u_{j}^{T}=G^{-1}$ for any complete $G$-orthonormal set.
>
> (Hint: expand an arbitrary vector in terms of this set).

I have proved that $\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_{n}\}$ is a basis. But I do not know how to continue.

Answer (score 2):

We know $\displaystyle u_i^T G u_j = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }i=j, \\ 0 & \text{if }i\ne j. \end{cases}$

How to prove that
$$
u^T G\left(\sum_{j=1}^n u_j u_j^T\right) = u^T,
$$
so that
$$
G\left(\sum_{j=1}^n u_j u_j^T\right) = I\text{ ?}
$$

It is enough to show this for $u=u_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, since these elements form a basis.
$$
\begin{align}
u_i^T G\left(\sum_{j=1}^n u_j u_j^T\right) & = \cdots+u_i^T (Gu_i u_i^T) + \cdots \\[12pt]
&  = \cdots+(u_i^T G u_i) u_i^T+\cdots.
\end{align}
$$
The other terms are $0$, and this term is $u_i^T$.

A similar argument works if you commute the two factors.

Comment: $(\sum^{n}_{j=1}u_{j}u^{T}_{j})Gu_{i}=u_{i}$, but what is next step?

Comment: Let $M=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n u_j u_j^T\right)G$.  Then $Mu_i=u_i$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$.  As mentioned, $u_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ are a basis.  So if $u$ is any vector at all, we can write $u = \sum_{j=1}^n c_i u_i$ for some scalars $c_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$.  You have $Mu$ $= M(c_1 u_1+\cdots+c_n u_n$ $= (c_1Mu_1)+\cdots+(c_n M u_n)$.  As just mentioned, that is equal to $c_1 u_1+\cdots + c_n u_n$.  And that is $u$.  So $Mu=u$.  This works regardless of which vector $u$ is, so $M$ must be the identity.

Comment: Where I wrote "It is enough . . . since these elements form a basis", what I meant is just what I wrote in more detail in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

First, since $G$ is symmetric positive definite, you know in particular that it is indeed invertible.

Now, let $T := \sum_{j=1}^n u_j u_j^T$. The question is, what is $TGe_k$ for each $k$?